# R Project: Loop calculation on files in folder

Tags: r, text-files, batch-processing

I have a bunch of text files in a folder. The script should read the whole list and do a calculation on each file. The result should be written in a "results.txt" file. I also want to have the name of the processed file in the results table and the result. But this line is still missing. But I don't know how to add it.
I am pretty far, but now I am stuck:

```
library(data.table)
ldf <- list() # creates a list
list_txt <- dir(pattern = "*.txt")
for (k in 1:length(list_txt)){
  ldf[[k]] <- fread(list[k], select = c("Count"))
  br=c(0,1,3,9,15,500) #Set breaks
  bins=c(0,1,2,3,4) #Set bins
  freq=hist(ldf[[k]]$Count, breaks=br, plot=FALSE)
  df=data.frame(bins, frequency=freq$counts)
  df$pct <- df$frequency*100 / sum(df$frequency)
  df$pct<-round(df$pct,digits=0)
  df$hscore<-df$pct * df$bins
  hscore=sum(df$hscore)
  cat(df$hscore,file="results.txt",sep="\n")
}
```

The error code I get is:

```
Error in hist.default(ldf[[k]]$Count, breaks = br, plot = FALSE) : 
  some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe `br=c(-Inf, 0, 1, 3, 9, 15, 500, Inf)`.

Comment: OK, but now are the error message is: Error in data.frame(bins, frequency = freq$counts) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 7

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bit more and came to this code, wich works without error messages:

```
    library(data.table)
ldf <- list() # creates a list
list_txt <- dir(pattern = "*.txt")
for (k in 1:length(list_txt)){
  ldf[[k]] <- fread(list_txt[k], select = c("Count"))
  br=c(-Inf,1,3,9,15,Inf) #Set breaks
  bins=c(0,1,2,3,4) #Set bins
  freq=hist(ldf[[k]]$Count, breaks=br, plot=FALSE)
  df=data.frame(bins, frequency=freq$counts)
  df$pct <- df$frequency*100 / sum(df$frequency)
  df$pct<-round(df$pct,digits=0)
  df$hscore<-df$pct * df$bins
  hscore=sum(df$hscore)
  cat(df$hscore,file="results.txt",sep="\n")
}
```

BUT, it creates a results.txt file with only 5 entries. When I call the list_txt, there are 164 files.

What could be the problem?